# How to block telnet access for one particular network from all networks except one using Extended ACL

Tags: routing, switch, networking, acl

Scenerio is given in the picture. [image: Block telnet using Extended ACL] I want to block all the networks except 192.168.5.128/25 from doing **telnet** of 192.168.5.0/25.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

On Switch0, you permit the single source subnet for telnet you want, deny all other telnet connections and then permit everything else.

```
1000 permit tcp 192.168.5.128/25 192.168.5.0/25 eq 23
1010 deny tcp any 192.168.5.0/25 eq 23
9999 permit ip any any
```

Comment: Unless the switch is layer 3, that ACL has to go on Router 0.

Comment: The 2960 should support extended ACLs. Putting it on the router doesn't prevent telnet from within 192.168.5.0/25.